# How to copy files based on file type

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

I have a folder which contains subfolders. In these subfolders are both .jpg and .mov files.

What I want to do is duplicate the tree into another root folder, but include only the .mov files.

Is there a terminal command I can issue that will do this like magic? I'm hoping there might be a linux guru out there with ninja-like skills who can save me a lot of time.

Example:

Current:

```
Pictures
-- 2014
----- January
--------- file1.jpg
--------- file1.mov
----- February
--------- file1.jpg
--------- file1.mov
----- March
--------- file1.jpg
--------- file2.jpg
----- April
--------- file1.mov
--------- file2.mov



Desired:
Pictures
-- 2014
----- January
--------- file1.jpg
----- February
--------- file1.jpg
----- March
--------- file1.jpg
--------- file2.jpg



Movies
-- 2014
----- January
--------- file1.mov
----- February
--------- file1.mov
----- April
--------- file1.mov
--------- file2.mov
```

Comment: The answer will differ ever so slightly on Linux from OS X.

Comment: Is this something you just need to do once, or will you need to repeat this action, sorting new pictures and movies into their respective directories?

Comment: Just need to do it once. I realized that my photo collection is huge, mainly because of the videos, so my idea is to make a parallel folder that matches the tree structure, and only contains the videos. Then in the future I can sort them manually as they come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `find` with `dirname`. Should work in the same way both in Linux and in MacOS. This is a shell script that should work in `bash`.

**Note:** to make sure you don't run it in the wrong place or with wrong values of `$source` and `$target` I prefixed all essential commands with `echo` so that it will *print* the command, rather than *execute* it. Make sure it does what you expect, then remove all `echo` (e.g. replace `echo mkdir ...` with just `mkdir ...`). This is a common precaution when writing complicated shell scripts.

```
source="/path/to/source"
target="/path/to/target"
cd "$source"
find . -type f -name '*.mov' | 
    while read fn ; do 
        path=`dirname $fn` 
        echo mkdir -p "$target/$path"  # -p is essential here
        echo cp "$fn" "$target/$path/"
    done
```

Here we iterate over the list of `*.mov` files in the `$source` directory, and for each file we extract the directory name using `dirname`. Then we create the corresponding subdirectory in the `$target` using `mkdir -p` (which will create all the required subdirectories and will not fail if the directory already exists) and finally copy the file.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `rsync`, I hope the syntax is the same on OS X

```
rsync -vrR --include="*.jpg" --include="*/" --exclude="*" /path/to/source /path/to/target
```

You will need to run two separate commands for *.mov and *.jpg since the target dirs are different

Comment: Nice one line solution. Although I didn't try it because I ended up using a GUI tool instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

In case it will help someone, I actually found a simpler solution that doesn't require the command line. I used FreeFileSync to copy the files to the new tree, then went back and used finder to remove the files that were copied over. Still a two-step process, but it was simple since it did not use the command line.

FreeFileSync has filtering, so I was able to isolate only the videos to copy over.

Removing the videos from the pictures folder was as simple as using finder's search capability and filtering on video file types only. Then one delete killed them all at once.